# How can I connect to a MiniKF k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I installed an arrikcto/minikuf in order to have a minikf locally, but I need to connect to its k8s cluster to do port forward over its S3, in order to do this, I copied the ./kube/config of the vagrant host into the localhost but this didn't work.

So the question is how can I connect with its cluster?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error are you getting when you try to run `kubectl` commands?

Comment: I try to run kubectl out of the minikf vagrant.